# Detecting caller and identifying threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, stack-trace

So I have a class in which I need to know if it was instantiated by a thread. Now I know that this can be achieved through using a `StackTraceElement` and going through the current stacktrace, however I need to know only if the class was called by a running thread not a parent thread.

Example:

I have a parent thread that manages the entire application and it controls other child threads that do whatever it is that they are assigned as well as classes that are running on the parent thread itself. I need to know if the code that instantiated a class was / is running on a parent or child thread, or just the default main method.

Application:

Flexibility. The class(es) that I am working on is designed to be flexible in the sense that it is both thread safe and can be integrated with less advanced or non-multi-threaded programs.

Comment: But any class can be instantiated by one thread and then handed over to another, or several others.

Comment: Yes but I need to know specifically if a class was instantiated by a thread, not if it was instantiated by a class running on the main thread, or a class  that is not a child thread itself running on another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the constructor of those class(es) to print current thread. Add the thread details onto a logger and then you can filter out which instances were NOT created using your `main` thread.

Just for quick illustration, I would give you some code in Scala:

This is how you can get current thread.

```
scala> Thread.currentThread
res23: Thread = Thread[main,5,main]
```

Modify class constructor.

```
scala> class A{ println(Thread.currentThread) }
defined class A
```

Now everytime an instance is created, print it to stdout ( or logger in your case )

```
scala> new A
Thread[main,5,main]
res24: A = A@5e99b9c
```